# autossh not working in background

Tags: ssh-tunnel

I am trying to setup autossh to run a tunnel to my VPN server. If I use

```
autossh -M 0 -o "ServerAliveInterval 30" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -R 10000:localhost:22 console@<myvpnip>
```

it seems to work well and I can use the tunnel.

However, if I add a `-f` flag to run in the background

```
autossh -f -M 0 -o "ServerAliveInterval 30" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -R 10000:localhost:22 console@<myvpnip>
```

I get the following when trying to use the tunnel.

> Connection refused

What is going on here? Is there a way to log any errors while running it in the background?

Answer (score 4):

Were you able to enter the password when you used the `-f` flag? From the autossh man page:

> Note that there is a crucial a difference between -f with autossh, and -f with ssh: when used with autossh ssh will be unable to ask for passwords or passphrases

You can still use the `-f` flag, but then you can't use password authentication. Instead use [public key authentication](https://www.debian.org/devel/passwordlessssh) with an `authorized_keys`-file on the VPN server. Then it should work with `autossh -f -M 0 -N -o "ServerAliveInterval 30" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -R 10000:localhost:22 console@<myvpnip>`. Note the extra `-N` option to `ssh`, useful for just forwarding ports.

You should be able to see debug info with `tail -f /var/log/syslog` or with `journalctl -f`.

Comment: I already had the password turned off and the auth keys turned on, but thats a good thought. The syslog is a good resource though, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It turns out I needed some more flags. I think the problem was that I needed to suppress some unwanted return data (like giving me a command line). It worked well with this

```
autossh -M 0 -o "ServerAliveInterval 30" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -fN -T -R 10000:localhost:22 console@<myvpnip>
```

Comment: Thank you. Based on this answer the following worked for me: `autossh -fN -T -R ...`